# web request in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webrequest

I want to do a web request in a asp.net core project. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to send the data in the request:

```
using System.Net;

...

//encoder
UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();

//data
string data = "[\"some.data\"]";

//Create request
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, secret);

//Set data in request
Stream dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
dataStream.Write(enc.GetBytes(data), 0, data.Length); 


//Get the response
WebResponse wr = await request.GetResponseAsync();
Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I don't get an error, the request was send but it doesn't seem to send the data with the request. 
I also can't give the length of the data with the request. Is this a core issue? (ps: The credentials are send correctly)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close the question, because it can't be answered (see OP's answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it. There was a bug in my external API code where I resolved the API request. The code in my question works (If someone wants to use it).

PS: I edit the code with the remark of ycrumeyrolle

Answer (score 1):

You may be facing a synchronization context problem.
Try to await the asynchronous methods like `GetRequestStreamAsync()` and `GetResponseAsync()` instead of getting the Result property.

```
//Set data in request
Stream dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();

//Get the response
WebResponse wr = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

Comment: Changed the code. This change did not resolve the problem but is idd more logical (problem was in my api that I was calling see answer below). Thxs for the help!